# How to attach array in php

Tags: php

I have an array structure like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file] => Array()
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file/2018-03-02] => Array()
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file/2018-03-03] => Array()
        )
)
```

how to add some an array on key specific like

```
[C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file] => Array('duck','buffalo')
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add a new key with a value or are you asking how to update an existing key?

Comment: I don't know, try `$arr[0]['C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file'] = ['duck','buffalo'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can do it like below:-

```
$array[0]['C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file'] = ['duck','buffalo'];
```

Output:-https://eval.in/984253

2.Or if some values are already present there:-

```
$array[0]['C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file'][] = 'buffalo';
```

Output:-https://eval.in/984254

3.Or if you want to search key first and then try to add:-

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   if(array_keys($value)[0] == 'C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file'){
      $array[$key]['C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file'][] = 'buffalo';
   }
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/984255

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you can assign an Array value to key specific like below:

```
$array[0]['C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file'] = Array('duck','buffalo');
$array[1]['C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file/2018-03-02'] = Array('duck','buffalo');
```

If you use `$array[0]['C:/xampp/htdocs/rosoka/file'][]` at left side like this it will again become an Array, hence accessing values will be changed.  There is no need of having `[]` again.